# XCODE: The specified item could not be found in the keychain

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter

[image]

So I reset my "login" keychain because previously even though I keep entering my login password, the password popup box wont go away.

Now I cant build my Flutter project in XCODE using a real IOS device. The error says
"The specified item could not be found in the keychain."

What should I do? Im on MacOS Catalina.

(BTW, Xcode Apple devs, maybe you can make your process noob-friendly? Maybe you can ease the building process up a bit? )

Comment: I restarted XCode, signed in my developer account and  when the login keychain popup came up, I entered my new login password and clicked "Always Allow"